# Clasificar la Informacion

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok aquí va, tengo una duda estoy haciendo una base de datos en SQL(sql server management studio) y quiero clasificar a los Estudiantes por Vacunados y no Vacunados. El problema radica alli tengo un campo como bit para discernir quien no y quien si esta vacunado Para clasificarlos en diferentes tablas dependiendo de esta.

No se como Clasificar los Estudiantes en las diferentes tablas, nose si se pueda con un check, procedure o trigger Para clasificarlos en las diferentes tablas de Vacunados y no Vacunados.

```
Create table Estudiantes
(
    Cedula varchar(15)
        constraint pk_Cedula primary key(Cedula)
        constraint ck_Cedula CHECK (Cedula LIKE '[0][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            OR  Cedula LIKE '[1][0-3][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
    CorreoElectronico varchar(30) 
        constraint ck_correoElec check (CorreoElectronico like '%@%'),
    Nombre varchar(15) not null,
    Apellido varchar(15) not null,
    FechaNac date,
    Facultadad int not null,
    Vacuna bit
        constraint ck_Vacuna check (Vacuna like '0' or  Vacuna like'1'),
    TipoVacuna int
        
)
```

```
Create table Vacunados
(
    Cedula varchar(15)
        Constraint pk_Cedula primary key(Cedula)
        Constraint fk_Cedula1 foreign key(Cedula) references Estudiantes(Cedula),
)
```

```
Create table NOVacunados
(
    Cedula varchar(15)
        Constraint pk_Cedula primary key(Cedula)
        Constraint fk_Cedula1 foreign key(Cedula) references Estudiantes(Cedula),
)
```

Comment: Tu duda es como llenar las tablas vacunados y no vacunados a partir de los datos de la tabla estudiante?

Comment: sip, apartir del campo de vacuna si es 0 entonces no vacunado, si es 1 pues si estan vacunados y dependiendo de esos dos valores que se anexen a la correspondiente tabla @Japv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para la tabla vacunados seria:

```
insert into vacunados(cedula)
select cedula 
from estudiantes
where vacuna = true
```

Se hace una consulta que va a filtrar a los estudiantes que han sido vacunados y los datos devueltos en esta consulta se insertan automáticamente en la tabla vacunados.

Para los no vacunados sería lo mismo pero cambiando la tabla y la condición.

Comment: Pregunta puedo hacer un trigger o procedimiento, para hacer esto de forma automática es decir cuando los datos sean ingresados en la tabla de estudiantes estos se anexen de forma automática? o algo asi?

Comment: Si, puedes hacerlo

Comment: okey muchas gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió marcala como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Ojo, si haces un trigger solo debes insertar en la tabla vacunado y no vacunado el registro en curso que estás insertando en la tabla estudiante

Comment: Es un enfoque diferente a la respuesta que te di

Comment: En la respuesta que te doy se asume que ya la tabla estudiante tiene datos y quieres seleccionar una parte de estos datos para llenar otra tabla, usar un trigger cambia las cosas

Comment: Por eso tienes que estar bien claro entre si usar un trigger o usar la respuesta que te doy

Comment: Necesito usar un trigger ya que los datos necesito que se actualicen sin que yo tenga que hacer la consulta